# Recursive stored procedure - insert sql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to generate a recursive stored procedure for the insert of a table of some hierarchical data.

I have three tables with the following design

Table A

```
Id.     uniqueidentifier
Name
Acronym
```

Table B

```
Id.        uniqueidentifier 
ParentId   uniqueidentifier (references TableA)
ChildId.   uniqueidentifier (references TableA)
Datestart  datetime
Dateend.   datetime
```

Table C

```
Id uniqueidentifier 
Datestart datetime 
Dateend datetime
AId uniqueidentifier (references TableA)
Left int
Right int
```

I am trying to do an insert into `TableC` with the values from the other two tables. `TableA` has the master data, and `TableB` has the parent child associations mentioned as per the date range.

As in as per quarter the parent child relationship can change, hence the `date start` and `date end` columns.

I want to write a recursive stored procedure with common table expression to do the inserts by combining the table A and B. I have tried searching for help online but most of the link has parent child relationship mentioned in the same table but not like my scenario.

Please let me know if somebody can help me.

Comment: Makes no sense me.   Please supply test data and desired output.

Comment: If you haven't figured it out, at least throwing in 2-3 lines of sample data for each of the 3 tables and 1,2 of what they have and 3 what you want.